# VS 2012 Add Service Reference Generating Incorrect Proxy Classes for OData Web Api

Tags: c#, proxy, odata, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a small project that has a rather simple web api.  We decided to go with the EntitySetController class for our controllers.  So far that all words great when testing the web api using Fiddler2, I can get to the odata api and make get requests on the controller.

Next part was creating a simple client to test the api in code, so I created a console application and I added a service reference, and pointed it to my api url.  I got the expected container and the 4 entity classes show up under the container.  The problem is that 2 of the entity classes don't show up using the original namespace, and 2 of the entities do.

This is the response to $metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <Schema Namespace="IRSI.Utilities.Model" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityType Name="Concept">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="Store">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="StoreNumber" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="ConceptId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="IRSI.Utilities.Electricity.Model" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityType Name="ElectricityInvoice">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="InvoiceNumber" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="InvoiceDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Amount" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="PreviousReadDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="CurrentReadDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="UsageDays" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="UsagekVA" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="FixedCharge" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="UsagekWh" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="RatekWh" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="AdditionalUsagekWh" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="RateAdditionalUsagekWh" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="CombustiblePurchase" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="CombustibleRate" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="EnergyPurchased" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="EnergyRate" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="OtherCharges" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="StoreId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="IRSI.Utilities.Water.Model" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityType Name="WaterInvoice">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="InvoiceDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="InvoiceNumber" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="Amount" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="PreviousRead" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="CurrentRead" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="UsageDays" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Usage" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="WaterCharge" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="StormDrainCharge" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="CCARCharge" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="SpecialCharge" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="StoreId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityContainer Name="UtilitiesContext" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="Concepts" EntityType="IRSI.Utilities.Model.Concept" />
        <EntitySet Name="Stores" EntityType="IRSI.Utilities.Model.Store" />
        <EntitySet Name="ElectricityInvoices" EntityType="IRSI.Utilities.Electricity.Model.ElectricityInvoice" />
        <EntitySet Name="WaterInvoices" EntityType="IRSI.Utilities.Water.Model.WaterInvoice" />
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

The proxies generated end up in:

```
IRSI.Utilities.Electricity.Model.ElecricityInvoice;
IRSI.Utilities.Water.Model.WaterInvoice;
IRSI.Utilities.Data.Client.UtilitiesService.Concept;
IRSI.Utilities.Data.Client.UtilitiesService.Store;
```

where IRSI.Utilities.Data.Client is the namespace of the console application

and the container is:

```
IRSI.Utilities.Data.Client.UtilitiesService.UtilitiesContext;
```

in the Web Api i'm setting up the routes like this:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.ContainerName = "UtilitiesContext";

        builder.EntitySet<Concept>("Concepts");
        builder.EntitySet<Store>("Stores");
        builder.EntitySet<ElectricityInvoice>("ElectricityInvoices");
        builder.EntitySet<WaterInvoice>("WaterInvoices");

        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
```

Am I missing something that is telling the client to generate the proxies differently.  Ideally it should be the original namespace like the namespace in the schemas.  Next best is fully use one schema, like all entities under the service namespace but not a mix of the 2.

Thanks, Junicus

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this method: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/11/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspx.

Comment: The problem with that package is that it's for ver 4 of OData, I'm using ver 3.  As far as I understand it this package is not compatible with older versions.